# How to know the default print size (ex. A3, A4) of each Excel file without opening it?

Tags: excel, printing

A strange problem is :
 I need to find print-size = A3 ones from hundreds of Excel file

How to know the default print size (ex. A3, A4) of each Excel file without opening it?

Answer (score 0):

Not. There's no sensible way to reproduce the details of an algorithm inside Excel short of running that algorithm.